# call delegate method if property changes

Tags: ios, delegates, nsthread, setter

I use RestKit with Object-mapping. This runs asyncronus and after receiving the Data from Server an object is updated.

The point is, i need to inform another class that a property of an object has changed.

Right now i run into an error:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1ae420: Tried to obtain the web 
lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. 
This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

I tried to overwrite the setter for the property, but it looks like the property is set in another thread, not the main thread. calling a delegate there does not work.

What can i do to solve this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need send message like this:

[obj performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(method)]

Comment: thanks ! needed to use `[delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(method)];` in setter method of my object.